# Why is this error happening in c?

Tags: c

I wrote  this code in CodeVisionAvr:

```
 //Global Variable
int second2=0; 
int sec_wait=14; 
bit waito_get=0,wait_to_string=0,error_reciv=0,fail_reciv=0;
.
.
.


  // in a function
while (second2 < sec_wait) { 
    if (wait_to_string || error_reciv || fail_reciv)
      second2= sec_wait;
}; 

if (wait_to_string == 0) {  
    printf("second2 %d sec_wait %d error_reciv %d fail_reciv %d  \r\n",
           second2, sec_wait, error_reciv, fail_reciv); 
};
```

Output of program is this:

```
second2 1 sec_wait 14 error_reciv 0 fail_reciv 0
```

How could it exit from `while` loop, when the condition is true for the value that are printed?

also I have 2 interrupt routines:

- interupt1: each 1 second second2++
- interupt2: get some character from USART and maybe set: wait_to_string ,error_reciv, fail_reciv.

My assembler code is:

```
; 0000 01EC               while(second2 < sec_wait){
_0x87:
    CALL SUBOPT_0xC
    CALL SUBOPT_0x5
    CP   R26,R30
    CPC  R27,R31
    BRGE _0x89
; 0000 01ED                 if(wait_to_string || error_reciv || fail_reciv)
    SBRC R3,7
    RJMP _0x8B
    SBRC R4,0
    RJMP _0x8B
    SBRS R4,1
    RJMP _0x8A
_0x8B:
; 0000 01EE                     second2 = sec_wait;
    CALL SUBOPT_0xC
    STS  _second2,R30
    STS  _second2+1,R31
; 0000 01EF               };
_0x8A:
    RJMP _0x87
_0x89:
```

Comment: what are the types of the variables?

Comment: @Bathsheba  int second2=0;
  int sec_wait=14;

bit waito_get=0,wait_to_string=0,error_reciv=0,fail_reciv=0;

Comment: And what is a bit? That's probably what's amiss here. Are other threads changing the variables?

Comment: @Bathsheba in interrupt function I changed variables and check at this line.

Comment: @mohammadrezapoushideh What is `bit` ?? Which is used as datatype of wait_to_string and other flags.

Comment: @Jeyaram The following table lists all the data types supported by the CodeVisionAVR C compiler, their range of possible values and their size:
  
Type Size (Bits) Range 
bit, _Bit 1 0 , 1

Comment: I've just seen your variables are modified in interrupt function. They should be marked as volatile then to force the compiler to read them in the loop, if not it is allowed to keep a cached value in registers and never see what has been changed. Could you try to build a real [mcve] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If variables can be modified by another thread, they should be marked as volatile.  If they are not, the compiler can use cached values in register and never reload them from memory. But if they are marked as volatile, the compiler shall reload them from main memory every time they are read.

Comment: why is second2 printing 1 then instead of 0?

Comment: I don't think he copiler is allowed to remove an infinite loop. That's breaking the *as-if* rule.

Comment: my variables are defined global, and they changed at the interrupt. but when I check the main program and print them, i get mistake output print.

Comment: I agree with @Quentin, an infinite loop may not be optimized away. Behavior still not explained... Mohammed, could you check the assembler?

Comment: check the assembler? what?

Comment: Take a debugger, run the program, have the debugger halt it at the loop, let the debugger show the assembler and check what assembler is generated for the loop. Sometimes that is the only way to understand what is happening. You could post the assembler with the question.

Comment: If you're compiling with GSS, you can also use the -S flag to output the generated assembly.

Comment: Is this still an answer? Most of the answer seems to no longer be relevant based on your own edit. Is the volatile thing an answer (if so, you should probably elaborate a bit)? If it's no longer an answer, you should delete it. Also, you should delete rather than strike out text - if you think it might be useful to future visitors, you could add a note at the end of an otherwise correct answer, or post a comment.

Comment: @Dukeling : this is an interesting remark. The last part (volatile) **is** the answer to the real problem, so I do not want to delete it, the former was the best I could imagine with only the original question. So I wonder what I really should do with that all ... maybe elaborate a little the now real answer.

Answer (score 0):

I marked variable as volatile and optimization level to low, my problem is solved.

```
volatile bit waito_get=0,wait_to_string=0,error_reciv=0,fail_reciv=0; 
volatile int second2=0;
volatile int sec_wait=14;
```

in CodeVisionAvr:
project/configure/c compiler/Optimization Level:Low
[image]

Comment: You can leave optimization level unchanged. As I wrote 2 hours ago in my comment, variables that can be modified by another thread **must** be marked as volatile. If you don't, the compiler can use cached values in register and never reload them from memory. But if they are marked as volatile, the compiler shall reload them from main memory every time they are read.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tested what you said, your right.marked variable as volatile is enough. thank you.